# How to add constraints to TimeType in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a builder which creates a select with options for hours and minutes for me:

```
$builder->add("startTime", 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TimeType', [
            "required" => true,
            "attr" => [
                "class" => "da_start",
                "id" => "da_start",
                "name" => "da_start"
            ],
            "data" => new \DateTime($start),
            "empty_data" => 'default',
            "label_attr" => [
                "class" => "da_start_label",
            ],
            "minutes" => $options['minutes'],
            "hours" => $start_hours_range,
            "constraints" => [
                new LessThanOrEqual([
                    "value" => $startCheck,
                    "message" => "1-2"
                ])
            ]
        ]);
```

Inside I have a constraints array and I want to validate this field so that if the value entered is greater than $startCheck variable an error message would be displayed.

$startCheck variable is generated like so:

```
$startCheck = new \DateTime('today' . $options['lessThan']);
```

and represents following dateTime Object:

```
DateTime {#1056 ▼
  +"date": "2021-09-23 06:30:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

which means that if I enter 06:45 to my form the validation should not pass.
Here is a dump of the value that I get from my form:

```
DateTime {#52 ▼
  +"date": "2021-09-23 06:45:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

And this value passes fine and is being written to DB. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turned out that Symfony generated not the date object of today, but the one for 1970-01-01 (Unix epoche start).

That's why $startCheck variable should be initialized like:

```
$startCheck = new \DateTime('1970-01-01T' . $options['lessThan']);
```

Kind of dirty, but this wotks fine for this type of comparison.